# How can I change the name of a key using jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, jbuilder

I have an `index.json.jbuilder` which looks like this:

```
json.results do |result|
    json.array! @artists do |artist|
      json.extract! artist, :id, :name
    end
  end
```

This produces the follow JSON format:

```
{"results": [{"id": 2, "name": "A-Austr"},{"id": 3,"name": "Abacus"}]}
```

I want to change the name of the key "name" to "text". Is there way to do this in the jbuilder? I don't want to change the name of the field in the database and would prefer not to have to do this using JS once the data is received. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.extract! artist, :id, :name` is essentially the same thing as:

```
json.id artist.id
json.name artist.name
```

You can replace `json.name` with `json.text` for your use-case.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much